# Plot two figures and connect them

Tags: plot, axis

I want to plot two different functions in two separate pair of axis, one above the other. Besides, I have to draw a dotted line between the two so as to mark some interesting points. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The answer is: yes, if you add a mwe we'll tell you how.

Comment: You can do something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230070/how-to-draw-line-through-group-plots-in-pgfplots