# How to draw lines across several subplots created using pgfplotslibrary groupplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw, groupplots

In the following just a minimal example to work with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=left plots,
    group size=1 by 2,
    vertical sep=2*\baselineskip},
  trig format=rad,
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=left,
  ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2,
  xmin=0, xmax=4.2*pi,
  samples=100]
\nextgroupplot[
  xtick={
    0,%
    1.5707963267948966192313216916398,% pi/2
    3.1415926535897932384626433832795,% pi
    4.7123889803846898576939650749193,% 3*pi/2
    6.283185307179586476925286766559,% 2*pi
    7.8539816339744830961566084581988,% 5*pi/2
    9.4247779607693797153879301498385,% 3*pi
    10.995574287564276334619251841478,% 7*pi/2
    12.566370614359172953850573533118% 4*pi
  },
  xticklabels={
    $0$, 
    $\frac{\pi}{2}$, 
    $\pi$, 
    $\frac{3}{2}\pi$, 
    $2\pi$, 
    $\frac{5}{2}\pi$, 
    $3\pi$, 
    $\frac{7}{2}\pi$, 
    $4\pi$
  }]
\addplot[domain=0:4*pi]{sin(x)};
\nextgroupplot[
  xtick={
    0,%
    0.52359877559829887307710723054658,% pi/6
    2.0943951023931954923084289221863,% 2*pi/3
    3.6651914291880921115397506138261,% 7*pi/6
    5.2359877559829887307710723054658,% 5*pi/3
    6.8067840827778853500023939971056,% 13*pi/6
    8.3775804095727819692337156887453,% 8*pi/3
    9.9483767363676785884650373803851,% 19*pi/6
    11.519173063162575207696359072025% 11*pi/3
  },
  xticklabels={
    $0$, 
    $\frac{\pi}{6}$, 
    $\frac{2}{3}\pi$, 
    $\frac{7}{6}\pi$, 
    $\frac{5}{3}\pi$, 
    $\frac{13}{6}\pi$, 
    $\frac{8}{3}\pi$, 
    $\frac{19}{6}\pi$, 
    $\frac{11}{3}\pi$
  }]
\addplot[domain=0:4*pi]{sin(x-2*pi/3)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

I want to know how to draw lines across several plots, e.g. a line from ymin of the bottom plot to ymax of the top plot at pi/3.

This is a simple example, I could had a `\draw` line outside `groupplot` environment specifying the global coordinates but in more complex cases the global coordinates could be difficult to compute. I think that I could specify a node inside the top plot at `(ymax,pi/3)` and another node inside the bottom plot at `(ymin,pi/3)` and then, outside `groupplot` environment, using `\draw` with the previous nodes. I don't know if is the *right way* to draw across several plots and I din't find any example on the net.

Comment: Here's an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230070/how-to-draw-line-through-group-plots-in-pgfplots/230072#230072

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I liked the idea of the coordinates. Should I delete the question or is better if I mark it as a duplicate and then close it?

Comment: I closed. Up to you if you want to delete it or not, the benefit of not deleting is that if someone else finds this post before the other, they're given a pointer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This is why I asked. It isn't a problem for me if I have the risk that someone downvote it as long as it can be helpful to others, even if only as a pointer.